# Count and store a value in xcode

Tags: iphone, database

Hello everyone I would have a value for the need to save every time I press a button (count), virtually every time a user presses a button in my app should be pressed to keep count of the times (1,2,3,4, etc. etc.) the problem is that that data would be permanently saved, that is, even when you exit the app or restart the device should be saved on the iphone to find it and increase it reopened after the application.
Is there an easier way to CoreData or SqlLite to do this?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be use NSUserDefaults to do this, no need for a bigger data store if it's only an integer.

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

int buttonCount = 0;

// Do you count somewhere and add to buttonCount

[defaults setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:buttonCount] forKey:@"buttonPress"];
```

and to retrieve to number back just use

```
int buttonPress = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"buttonPress"] intValue];
```

Comment: Thanks and if i need to store also current datetime value in my NSUserDefault object? Is possible store 2 values? and how i can retrive just datetime value??? Thanks

Comment: you can store as many values as you'd like, just use different keys for each one.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a sample code:

To store it:

```
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger: intCount forKey:@"Count"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

To read it:

```
    intCount = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey: @"Count"];
```

Comment: It's worth pointing out that storing in this way is relatively cheap. You should just save every time the value changes. No need to be lazy about it.

Answer (score 0):

NSUserDefaults is the solution. Update the stored value in every button click....